# Node js: property not exisit

Tags: node.js

i'm new to node js and i'm creating my first API with the help of some tutorials .. in my code below i'm getting error that says :
`Property 'subscriber' does not exist on type 'Response<any, number>'.`
the error shows on every **res.subscriber** and its defined in the function middle wear below **function getSubscriber**
however, its already working code since i saw it on tutorial.
ican't figure out the problem can someone please help me?

code below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Subscriber = require('../models/subscriber')

// Getting all
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const subscribers = await Subscriber.find()
    res.json(subscribers)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
// Getting One
router.get('/:id', getSubscriber, (req, res) => {
  res.json(res.subscriber)
})

// Creating one
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const subscriber = new Subscriber({
    name: req.body.name,
    subscribedToChannel: req.body.subscribedToChannel
  })
  try {
    const newSubscriber = await subscriber.save()
    res.status(201).json(newSubscriber)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})

// Updating One
router.patch('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.name != null) {
    res.subscriber.name = req.body.name
  }
  if (req.body.subscribedToChannel != null) {
    res.subscriber.subscribedToChannel = req.body.subscribedToChannel
  }
  try {
    const updatedSubscriber = await res.subscriber.save()
    res.json(updatedSubscriber)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})

// Deleting One
router.delete('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await res.subscriber.remove()
    res.json({ message: 'Deleted Subscriber' })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})

async function getSubscriber(req, res, next) {
  let subscriber
  
  try {
    subscriber = await Subscriber.findById(req.params.id)
    if (subscriber == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find subscriber' })
    }
    
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  res.subscriber = subscriber
  next()
}

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Why do you need to put an object into the the object response? Can you add some more informations? I don't understand the necessity to put the logic of your API into the response

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man igot this from a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgTGADljAeg  it describes the idea at 21:00 but i didn't really understand it

Comment: This is apparently a TypeScript error as regular Javascript would not generate that error.  Are you using TypeScript or some similar typed system?  If so, you can't just freely add properties to the `res` object without doing the appropriate typing stuff to make the type-checking happy.  Regular Javascript would not have this error.